# FlutterFire Messaging: An error occurred in your background messaging handler

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-hive

I'm using firebase messaging and flutter hive package, i'm making a chat application and save incoming messages into hive so the chat also works offline.
I'm using firebase messaging onBackgroundMessage handler when notification is received and the app is closed i do this to store the message data in hive while app isn't running:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
    final RemoteMessage message) async {
  if (message.data["Type"] == "ChatMessage") {
    //*******WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
        await ChatFirestore.getDocumentSnapshot(
            collectionName: "Messages", documentId: message.data["MessageId"]);
    if (documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists) {
      final MessageModel newMessage = MessageModel.fromMap(
          map: documentSnapshot.data(),
          fromMe: ChatHelpers.isReceivedMessageFromMe(
              otherChatUserId: message.data["SenderId"]),
          status: 2,
          receiptDeviceTimestamp: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
          deleted: false);
      await ChatHive.saveMessageFromNotification(message: newMessage);
      await ChatHelpers.updateAppBadge(inForeground: false);
      await ChatFirestore.modifyDocumentSnapshot(
        collectionName: "Messages",
        documentId: newMessage.id,
        newInformation: {
          "Status": 2,
          "ReceiptDeviceTimestamp": newMessage.receiptDeviceTimestamp,
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

But i always get this error in the log:

```
I/flutter (13090): FlutterFire Messaging: An error occurred in your background messaging handler:
I/flutter (13090): NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'id' was called on null.
I/flutter (13090): Receiver: null
I/flutter (13090): Tried calling: id
```

Here is my **saveMessageFromNotification** Function:

```
await Hive.initFlutter();
if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(6)) {
   Hive.registerAdapter<MessageModel>(MessageModelAdapter());
}
final Box<MessageModel> messagesBox =
    await Hive.openBox<MessageModel>("MessagesBox");
messagesBox.put(message.id, message);
```

Here is my flutter doctor result:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale
    en-SA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.58.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap this in an IF statement, to check if message isn't null.

```
if(newMessage!=null) await ChatFirestore.modifyDocumentSnapshot(
        collectionName: "Messages",
        documentId: newMessage.id,
        newInformation: {
          "Status": 2,
          "ReceiptDeviceTimestamp": newMessage.receiptDeviceTimestamp,
        },
      );
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem has been solved.
The problem was that i was getting chat user id from a static variable in constants class, but when the app in background, all variables become null, so i have to get it from hive, note that you have to initialize hive again and register used adapter again if you want hive to work in background.
Thank you.